# Expand $(\frac{x}{3}+\frac{x^2}{4})^2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$(\frac{x}{3}+\frac{x^2}{4})^2$ I know that the special product of $(a+b)^2$ is $a^2+2ab+b^2$ they said the answer is $\frac{x^4}{16}+\frac{x^3}{6}+\frac{x^2}{9}$ I don't understand how they got $\frac{x^3}{6}$

Comment: $2 a b=2\frac x3 \frac {x^2}{4}=\frac{2\cdot x \cdot x^2}{3\cdot 4}=\frac{2x^3}{12}=\frac{x^3}{6}.$

Answer (score 5):

Put $a = \frac{x}{3} $ and $b = \frac{x^2}{4} $, then

$$ (a+b)^2 = a^2 + 2ab + b^2= \left( \frac{x}{3} \right)^2 + 2 \left( \frac{x}{3} \right) \left( \frac{x^2}{4}\right) + \left(  \frac{x^2}{4} \right) ^ 2 = \frac{ x^3}{9} + \frac{x^3}{6} + \frac{x^4}{16}$$

Notice the in the middle of the second equality, I am taking the half in both parts of the fraction.